# How to make canvas scrollable after scaling in Android Studio(Java)

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am developing an app in which I am showing canvas above pdf file so I can annotate it with free hand drawing to give remarks. My problem is that my canvas is zoomable but not scrollable. I am able to scale the canvas but unable to scroll it. Zoomed area is not scrollable please help how I can achieve it.  My code is below

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.example.smartschool.ViewPDFFileActivity;

public class PaintView extends PDFView {
    static Path drawPath;
    //drawing and canvas paint
    private static Paint drawPaint;
    private static Paint canvasPaint;
    //initial color
    static int paintColor = 0xFFFF0000;
    //stroke width
    private static float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
    //canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    //canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    //eraser mode
    private static boolean erase=false;
    boolean scaling=false;
    private float scaleFactor = 1.f;
    public  ScaleGestureDetector detector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    //constructor
    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
        setErase(erase);
    }
   
    private static void setupDrawing(){
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }

    //*************************************** View assigned size  ****************************************************

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }
  
    public static void setErase(boolean isErase){
        erase=isErase;
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        if(erase) {
            setupDrawing();
            int srcColor= 0x00000000;

            PorterDuff.Mode mode = PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR;
            PorterDuffColorFilter porterDuffColorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(srcColor, mode);
            drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(40);
            drawPaint.setColorFilter(porterDuffColorFilter);

            drawPaint.setColor(srcColor);
            drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(mode));

        }
        else {

            setupDrawing();

        }
    }

    //************************************   draw view  *************************************************************

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        drawCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.save();

        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap,0,0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.restore();


    }

    //***************************   respond to touch interaction   **************************************************

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);

        float touchX = event.getX()/scaleFactor;
        float touchY = event.getY()/scaleFactor;
        //respond to down, move and up events

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(ViewPDFFileActivity.isDrawEnabled)
                    drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(ViewPDFFileActivity.isDrawEnabled) {
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(ViewPDFFileActivity.isDrawEnabled) {
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    drawPath.reset();
                }
                
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        //redraw
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    //***********************************   return current alpha   ***********************************************
    public int getPaintAlpha(){
        return Math.round((float)STROKE_WIDTH/255*100);
    }

    //**************************************  set alpha   ******************************************************
    public void setPaintAlpha(int newAlpha){
        STROKE_WIDTH=Math.round((float)newAlpha/100*255);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(newAlpha);
    }
    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            if(ViewPDFFileActivity.isDrawEnabled) return true;
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5f));
            invalidate();
            ViewPDFFileActivity.pdfView.setMaxZoom(scaleFactor);
            ViewPDFFileActivity.pdfView.zoomTo(scaleFactor);
            ViewPDFFileActivity.pdfView.invalidate();

            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaling=true;
            return super.onScaleBegin(detector);

        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            super.onScaleEnd(detector);
            scaling=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use canvas.translate() ? (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#translate(float,%20float)). You know that when size of your image 1 and then you scale image to 2 concerning the centre - it means that you move origin (0,0) point to (-0,5, -0,5) . If now you translate canvas to   (-0,5, -0,5) then you will see top left corner of image .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support.....Can you please give me an example how to implement translate. I am using canvas.drawcolor(Color.Transaprent) to show pdf content as background. When I scale canvas its also scale background thats required .........but problem is that when I scroll canvas after zooming its background remains fixed (not moving)...how I can achieve it.

Comment: PDFView.java itself is a good example of using scale (zoom), translate (scroll).  PDFView has methods as moveRelativeTo() and moveTo()